# Writing D&D content (adventures, mostly) as a paying job, is it possible?

Tags: published-adventures, adventure-writing, publishing

I've heard of people who write adventures and sell them, for real-life money.

I'd like to know how is it possible, profitable, and if so where can I do it? I have rather good writing skills and experience with D&D 2nd-4th editions.

Any info on the subject would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you'll need to narrow this down to one specific edition for us to really answer it, the licenses under which each edition was published differ greatly.

Comment: Yes, people write RPG material for pay, most often as freelancers, a rare few as company staff. Beyond that basic confirmation, what this question is asking for is way, way too broad for our site's Q&A format. If you can narrow it down to one concrete problem or question, maybe by doing some Google research on freelancing in the RPG industry, perhaps we can help then.

Comment: I would prefer to work with the latest 5th edition because of the great reviews I red about it, but I would also like to hear about the "markets" of other editions (3.5 and 4 mostly.)

Comment: And yes, it is a broad question for me since I don't know anything about how this market works.

Comment: Hence the suggestion to get thee to Google. It's not much different from any other freelancing writing. If freelance writing in general is unfamiliar territory, this question re the RPG industry is very premature and you have some research to do. Forty years ago somebody could say, "hey I can do that" and send a typewritten manuscript to *Dragon*, but those days are long past. Already having a basic grasp of freelancing (researching submission policies/venues, writing to spec, and professional networking) appears to be current minimum necessary for entry, and that stuff is off-topic here.